# How to create responsive WinForm buttons to create a clickable single elimination brackets?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a single elimination tree that is created in WinForms in C#. In addition, the tree will be consists of clickable buttons that will go Green color to determine winner of related round and for the next round this colours will be referenced. Lastly, this tournament can be between 2 and 100 player so I need a responsive form that can show all the buttons at the same time or another technology like zooming related round can be used.

This is what I want to say by tournament brackets

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzCjI.png]

There are two main points that are unclear to me.
First: How to create the buttons in order like x, y coordinate.
Second: How to make it responsive for bigger number values like 100.

Comment: You definitely don't want to be dealing with absolute coordinates here... I'd see what layout panels could be leveraged for this, and challenge the WinForms requirement - could it be made in XAML/WPF, and perhaps hosted in a WinForms container?

Comment: That said I think your question is a bit too broad to be reasonably answerable on this site.

Comment: You are absolutely right , I m not asking for specific code or error instead I just want to learn possible ways to do . Coordinates are not problem at first .

Comment: I want program to run in c# ui as desktop app  by the way .